# Stop Google Drive for Desktop Hogging CPU after Boot?

Tags: windows, cpu-usage, google-drive, resource-usage, google-drive-file-stream

Every machine in my office has the google drive client taking upwards of 90% of CPU resources after boot/restart.This causes extreme system slowdown and effective downtime.

When I kill & restart the process, usage is back to normal and everything's fine.

Is there any reason why that happens and is there a way to sandbox or limit a program's cpu allocation? I've changed process affinity which helps a little bit, but I can't get the changes to stay after restart and it's kinda a hacky solution.

Comment: do you need the Google drive running always in the background?

Comment: yeah. my clients use gfd for everything and can't have it not running. I can't figure out why it uses so much cpu, why it works fine after restarting the process, and what to do about it.

Comment: is everything up to date? OS, drivers and google drive itself?

Comment: Yes. All systems all fully patched to the latest feature update of win10. I've also eliminated AV as the culprit, both our endpoint agent and windows defender by uninstalling our agent and disabling defender.

Comment: And its probably worth noting that when it is installed, our agent would spike for a bit after the drive process was killed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is Google Drive so heavy on my CPU?](https://superuser.com/questions/804205/why-is-google-drive-so-heavy-on-my-cpu)

Comment: I appreciate it. That article is close, but it mostly suggests that the issue is a bug and the only thing to do is to keep restarting the process. What else could I try? I'm working on a powershell script right now as a band-aid fix, [How to check if process is running properly in Powershell?](https://superuser.com/questions/1682641/how-to-check-if-process-is-running-properly-in-powershell), but would like something more permanent.